# how to post a base64 string to a server?

Tags: android, base64, http-post, image-uploading

i'm tring to post base64 string to server and it won't post maybe because the sting is too long and i got this messege `A connection to "server" was leaked. Did you forget to close a response body?`

this is my code

```
try {

            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            selectedImageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
            selectedImageBitmap.recycle();
            byte[] byteFormat = stream.toByteArray();
            stream.close();
            stream = null;
            // get the base 64 string
            String imgString = Base64.encodeToString(byteFormat, Base64.DEFAULT);
            selectedImageBitmap=null;
            System.gc();
            byteFormat=null;
            System.gc();
            Log.d("image",""+ imgString);

            Log.d("urlnya", "" + LOGIN_URL);
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(LOGIN_URL);
            HttpClient httpclientpost = new DefaultHttpClient();
            final HttpResponse responsepost = httpclientpost.execute(post);
            Log.d("respon post", "" + responsepost.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
            post.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

            json.put("user_id", 6);
            json.put("status", status_id);
            json.put("keterangan", ket);
            json.put("foto", imgString);


            Log.d("image",""+ encodedImage);

            StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(json.toString());
            post.setEntity(entity);
            HttpResponse responsepost2 = httpClient.execute(post);
            Log.d("respon post2", "" + responsepost2.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
            // checking log for json response
            Log.d("processing ", json.toString());

        } catch (JSONException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

i've tried to post base64 which is with this long 
`/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEB
         AQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQH/2wBDAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEB
         AQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQH/wAARCAQ4B4ADASIA
         AhEBAxEB/8QAHwAAAAYDAQEBAAAAAAAAAAAABAUGBwgJAgMKAAEL/8QAfBAAAQMCBQIDBAcGAwQE
         AAI7AQIDEQQFAAYSITEHQRNRYQgicYEJFDKRobHwFSNCwdHhM1LxFiRDYgoXcpIlNFNjgsLSGCZE
         VJOistQZNUVVVmRzg5XT4ic3RmV0doSUwyg2OGZ1d6Oks8TW8khXZ4WHprS2xYaWpafV/8QAHgEA
         AAcBAQEBAAAAAAAAAAAAAQIDBAUGBwAICQr/xABhEQABAwIEBAQEBAUDAgICASUBAgMRBCEABRIx
         BkFRYRMicYEHkaHwFDKxwSNC0eHxCBVSFmIkMxclQ2NyCRg0RIKSojVGU1RVc5PSJkVWZISUwjZm
         dIOVsnWFpLO0xNP/2gAMAwEAAhEDEQA/AOY5bKTqJO49PMR8N+eSZA4wVVlGFAqEbjmADIjnCibS
         N1KA3AA4gk7D7u0/D0wGfZBKjGxH+sDj79/wxmoWTZRvAjlIIB+d8ZAw8rUkK6C/TblB5/e+EhHh
         AJO5JPf5+Xl8MGDYlsdpHY/29MankpDiZGw1fzHb/ScDWEoWlCRBnYwdwfjufKcJOkggiCAL/t9M
         SKlAwY5XIk9dv1548g/w7naZPyH6P4Y2jnkj1wITSTunadtyd/wx8NI8gnUklPYgz+JHnHOEPETM
         2B2JJ5W5W7YT1J6j548EagJAUOJMennjQu3trMhWkzIhKfUxPPfApKVBQkKEzyDvt6/lgQhIO6uB
         zv8ArtjpIukiDFhJHLr1+ntgiVlJsZAsO4+9pmMEpoikmFAnyj8v1xjYKcgbkQJ539T2woWWkKiU
         9+fnET8P1GDJFG24mAjzBPHn3jBDUQJj/PzwY1Mb+/pb05CfsQi/DUD72w85H4f3xsTsQB6RP88K
         1y1EiUNg+W5mCR6RxgKbUqTLZ+9X9MGS+hXa07jt6dccKptYuI25xeB17nb6csFKDI3jaB+v18hg
         xo16zG593cE9hInv5cYwXbahJENqE8kFR+XHw7YFMspYEwQvTHM/HbtG0zGDyhUn6z6d49ux7SC1
         IUAUmenP129t/wC+DBlJKhA228h3GFFTEpWB3gCfh5YTbCyNye+2w33H4/0weMOiQoniDMeUGfL+
         W/xw1dBNuXL6TP3++GTid4G230n1wsaFQ9wHkkfjPPx/1woWUpWdIJEem/fvx2GEhQVKDp1HaRB2
         439f9O8CMKVl2BKDKvP039f192I1xrST1O17fcW7jvOIV9CrzvtJm9/ToesfueNpgpSBulQJ4G3J
         EidvTCxthT4IBABgbcgz345O388Ji3pDhQTuTJI2gcCYgxhYUrICEBA321fKPIdzOGbnL3+/piGq
         VwQgjaDB9j9b/SOeFTaG9Sx6oJnYdzzyduMODTUxhCvUeXp6/P44QltStCxED3SOfie2HLt+l1DQ
         I/iTOwB7H9enzwrTpClAc567SRf09RyOIZwysn72wurKzqSAIkhvtHZPPP674eKw0klnggSZMdtP
         z/nhu7PTJIGhPujw5M9vd7/CP54ebL9IoBk6dhO0yeUeY49efXFny2m8wO8wetyUg8uff5Ww0Ugk
         XERz6ff3fC4tNAHAkgiPEjcD17fHn0w5Vqth1pIIiByE/wDMO0flgmsNFLYJb/4p843keX3wcPFZ
         7P4i2h4UyEjYgd+OPId+/pONAyylUSAE3kbg9RF+REyN474aqsDPOw5X+vr9Ma7LalLca3EaiP4e
         fdgx8/PjD52qnKWo22SgcDsgev8ATBRZLK214RLJkA8wd/d/5RvtHPww4DFvUkEIbj7xsAPIYvFG
         0mnbAMlSo6cgJgGDhg4FLPKBN+XL17fcYxYQqRHl98c/l85wcMI93fsfiCJP98bKajWmCURsN9z3
         77eXy+WDFNIdQhEEwI34nmD/AKYdBwSrqSLcrb++/vywTwlRME9IHp/Xf7GLYmPIAT92Nim0qEED
         v2Eb+e2+ByKR3/JO2w3MfERjYmmVIlG8+Qj57YkWFnSB2t6Tsff+nqiW1EytMCPkbG8+uEvV2Jut
         B0kJO25QjsR3Injb8MNNmbJygiqbX4biVCPeDR2OraCD3EcRvMDEkE0a1bpTBHcGExvtI43ny/Hd
         J5ovuWbLQ1irjU06alpqSnU04dR1QCgrB/hUYIB+WHTiWVsrcqClptKCStawgEJSJgnewmCbbcpw
         NE1WLqG2aRp2peUtCW22G1OLBJQArygkpuJkcxFsV+Z06bsredqfESzu6dLbTHIQpXZIPI+8TO+I
         uZkUbKt1tIDiUPeGFn3VcJPCfVRG3YDnEmOtXU22mtfFLXtIp0/WAgNtpQSPCcge45B2Pp69sV8Z
         pzo/c3HUUr6nB9YUvUWzuBp31a1A7gxGMJ4y4rynL3XWaQpU9rUlTqXEKClAIuBqtBJv2Ji049q/
         Bj/TZnfGrlLmGctrbo3ENOFpTdS0Gwom7h0AE+SSJ5mDg0r8yrLqyFuCJ2C3QFQQd/e+MzOERcKp
         +unSooPvcLVvq1ckq7z+G+E8ldU4sLeK1EmTBVvyYIn8MKS30zlSr3W3FEaRwe5HkCcefs5zqur3
         VqDyy2uT4YCSdx0FkxED17AfTjgT4V8N8C0lO1l9Cl+qaQ0k1BK1ISpKA2TpJiDJuqTJttglpKfx
         XkJWohU7kb7AgckfP4+XZzLLblJLZCtaS5wqI2Kp2P8ATyxvteTa+rW0sUL0KWdwlSQQCO+g7n8f
         jh9sqZDqh4RcoiZfhQUokge9Gykes98GyHJMxzFY8Np1KCoSpTapiU/lhMHcEE+hucTnGXxU4V4H
         pnKjNa2ncrUIUW6VNVTtBBFjq1rmyxpgJnuN8Etts9E+lCFobQ4UpBUGWiZJMydMnjYzwd8L205d
         pacNrUoKSCSD4TfEggRpmNsPdZciUCW0F6klZbSNlgnVKht7mxgjAyuyGpOp2npVhtIEfvFT37BH
         qOPynG05L8NGaUpqqr+JMLLfnDhA0KtNk7ECOvPHzU+LX+rjiDih6py7h5K6VpMtipSlgsQA4g6Q
         kL1kBaTOoSB+XlhH0jVGtBShKUEAAlLSUnYJ76R+jgpu9pWttxaFSJUoAwNiOD5wNogeXG+FSLPV
         0ygCytIiDGomRt5enbAj6vKdC0EmNwR+G4+H3bbY0RthimZDDFMlpIEahq1D8ouTsPS/1x43zLNM
         0zl41Wb1btW/qkatIAMJEhKQlMAAbiNvXEe7pRuU7g1EfY33HET29MJGuAW2obECQdXeZkHbfj4c
         4kxXWBh8SWAokEbERwQNwk8/y+GEdWZKQtKopoO8e/EzP/Jxhi4FImElXcX2j9Zj9JwlTvIbgFJE
         ETO02FrAbDpHS0YiLmnLzNcl1cJSstL4ba2KlJI3IkydhxA5xGLNlgeo1AoXsdAI1BMEgR9kb7Tv
         8sWN3vIr6g4E0hMIUBClHckRuEd9vh6YjpnTJFa2R/uDhPuQdJUP4ef3f8vLDdDhtIi1gbbx1m5I
         mMXDKcwbJSkqAiBBIjl1M2/UHviCVQ0Q4tB/xArmQRtO08/r5Yzp6dXc8/P7UbfyHw9cOTmHLTtP
         UvKVSrbWFpB2IiVK7FHn/bywTUdmcW5JZUQkp7EbyP8Al/Pv6YVU6TAmLR9+8X3mMXX8WktphUgB
         IiRew6/Pc/vjVQ0igkGdikeU8nj4nCkp6UmJ9P8AKex/Pvg3Ysz2lOhg7Acg+vMJ+7v+ODJiiUgg
         FEKBgg8yBsDInnDVTsbA/L079f264YrrAVQJJi4F+Ynnz++xMqimNMDm`

or maybe longer i dont know exacly. but it won't post because it prosses too much string (maybe)
please help how can i post base64 to server. thank you

Comment: Take a look at http://square.github.io/retrofit/ to simplify work with REST, also check the size limit of post request at BE, usually multipart requests are used for image uploading.

Comment: is it must be use library?

Comment: can you give me some example how to post base64 using retrofit? @Ufkoku

Comment: https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-how-to-upload-files-to-server

Comment: base64 has so many string. can string like that be uploud?

Comment: the size of POST-body or multipart request parts are limited by config of your BE.

Comment: i think retrofit is post image without change it to base64